# how to encrypt and decrypt in python & vb.net compatible with AES?

Tags: python, vb.net, encryption, cryptography

Question for anyone who believes in Python and VB 2008:

I'm building a system to raspberry pi board that needs to be operated by a remote computer with Windows operating system, but can not make the code in python aes to be compatible with vb.net code.

I would like to know how do I generate a code for vb which has result compatible with the code from Python with AES.

How to encrypt and decrypt in python & vb.net compatible with the AES code below?

python code with AES:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64


def EncodeAES(secret, s):
    BLOCK_SIZE = 32
    PADDING = '{'
    pad = BLOCK_SIZE - len(s)
    pad = pad % BLOCK_SIZE
    pad = pad * PADDING
    pad = s + pad
    cipher = AES.new(secret)
    c = cipher.encrypt(pad)
    enc = base64.b64encode(c)
    return enc


def DecodeAES(secret, e):
    PADDING = '{'
    cipher = AES.new(secret)
    b64 = base64.b64decode(e)
    c = cipher.decrypt(b64)
    dec = c.rstrip(PADDING)
    return dec

secret2 = 'x\x90\xd4~\x18\x8a\xb6\x9f\xc7\x82/DI\x1d\xa7\xb9\xdf\xad\x80S\x95\x90\x13}T,\x89/\xcf\x1a\xe9\xc2'

# create a cipher object using the random secret
# generate a random secret key
#BLOCK_SIZE1 = 32
#secret2 = os.urandom(BLOCK_SIZE1)
print (('secret string:', secret2))

# encode a string
encoded = EncodeAES(secret2, 'password')
print (('Encrypted string:', encoded))

# decode the encoded string
decoded = DecodeAES(secret2, encoded)
print (('Decrypted string:', decoded))
```

I found a DES code (vb.net & python compatible, only for sample):

vb.net DES:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim temp As String = ""
        Dim from_pyton As String = "rhxUtKPuxriRaPd/MDgliw=="
        temp = Crypto.Encrypt("I love security")
        MsgBox(temp)

        temp = Crypto.Decrypt(from_pyton)
        MsgBox(temp)

        End
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Crypto
    Private Shared DES As TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()

    Private Shared MD5 As MD5CryptoServiceProvider = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()

    Public Shared Function MD5Hash(ByVal value As String) As Byte()
        Return Crypto.MD5.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value))
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal stringToEncrypt As String) As String
        Crypto.DES.Key = Crypto.MD5Hash("L6#F&,q2$xLx")
        Crypto.DES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
        Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt)
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(Crypto.DES.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Decrypt(ByVal encryptedString As String) As String
        Dim result As String
        Try
            Crypto.DES.Key = Crypto.MD5Hash("L6#F&,q2$xLx")
            Crypto.DES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
            Dim array As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString)
            result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Crypto.DES.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(array, 0, array.Length))
            Return result
        Catch expr_4D As Exception
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(expr_4D)
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
        End Try
        result = Nothing
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

python DES compatible: (need install pyDes lib: http://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html)

```
from pyDes import *
import hashlib
import base64
key = hashlib.md5("L6#F&,q2$xLx").digest()
data = "I love security"
k = triple_des(key, ECB, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", pad=None, padmode=PAD_PKCS5)
d = k.encrypt(data)
base64Encrypted = base64.b64encode(d)
print ("Encrypted: %r" % base64Encrypted)
base64Decrypted = base64.b64decode(base64Encrypted)
print ("Decrypted: %r" % k.decrypt(base64Decrypted))
```

Comment: So which are you having the problem with? AES, DES, both?

Comment: With AES. How to obtain the same result: from python code ​​to VB .net 2008 code?

Comment: If your question is about AES remove the code sample related to DES and show your VB code for AES…

Comment: Sorry, I put the code DES only for sample of which the results of the codes are compatible. I would like to know how do I generate a code for vb which has result compatible with the code from Python with AES.